# How to instruct webpack to watch changes in an NPM linked dependency (package)

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm trying to figure out how to get webpack to watch an NPM linked dependency. I've tried to add an explicit entry pointing into the package, and I've tried to both explicitly includ it and also not excluding /node_modules/ (which is quite common).

The scenario I want to achieve is as follows: I want to separate out parts of my react-based applications into component libraries (NPM packages).

Both the main package and the dependencies are written in ES6, so I've created a small gulp script that watches for changes in the dependent project, and transpiles its source (src/) to lib.

I've used `npm link` to wire in the dependent package so that I don't need to pack/publish/reinstall it every time I make a change.

When I make changes to the dependent package, the gulp task transpiles the code OK.

It is with the last part that I am struggling; getting `webpack watch` to trigger a re-bundling when the dependency is refreshed by the aforementioned gulp task.

Comment: I'm having the same situation, do you have any way to solve it? I have a project like:
a -> b -> c
b depends on a, c depends on b. I want to be able to change a or b, and compile c once b is compiled.

Comment: Did we ever come up with a specific approach for resolving this? In the age of monorepos, it seems like an obvious issue. It'd be great if we had an example repo!

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44166532/1248811

Comment: The solution from @anytimecoder works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you transpiler script doesn't delete your old `/lib` dir, but overwrites files instead.

I had a similar problem with Webpack dev server not seeing changes because I was removing the `/lib` dir before every transpile.

Comment: This works, just tried myself. In my case I'm working with Typescript
Once I removed the "rimraf" removing the "lib" (or any name you have), it worked.
I have webpack watching the final project, while TS watches the code from the linked dependency