# webpack to also watch node modules for hot reloading is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

I am using `npm link` in our main application to point to the `submodules packages`.
`npm link` is working fine for me,I want to add one more feature as soon as the references place through `npm link` gets updated reload the app as there would be some updates in `submodules packages`

I am following this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522721/how-to-watch-certain-node-modules-changes-with-webpack-dev-server)

I have updated the file `node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js` with `followSymlinks: true,`

added `watchOptions` to `webpack.dev.babel.js`

```
watchOptions: {
    ignored: [
    /node_modules([\\]+|\/)+(?!cookie)/,
    /cookie([\\]+|\/)node_modules/    
]},
```

After this, if I am trying to make changes in `cookie` node-modules the webpack is not hot reloading.

Here is my

```
/**
 * DEVELOPMENT WEBPACK CONFIGURATION
 */

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');
const logger = require('../../server/logger');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const pkg = require(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'package.json'));
const dllPlugin = pkg.dllPlugin;

const plugins = [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // Tell webpack we want hot reloading
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: true, // Inject all files that are generated by webpack, e.g. bundle.js
    templateContent: templateContent(), // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define
  }),
  new CircularDependencyPlugin({
    exclude: /a\.js|node_modules/, // exclude node_modules
    failOnError: false, // show a warning when there is a circular dependency
  }),
];

module.exports = require('./webpack.base.babel')({
  // Add hot reloading in development
  entry: [
    'eventsource-polyfill', // Necessary for hot reloading with IE
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/app.js'), // Start with js/app.js
  ],

  watchOptions: {
      ignored: [
        /node_modules([\\]+|\/)+(?!cookie)/,
        /cookie([\\]+|\/)node_modules/
      ]
    },

  // Don't use hashes in dev mode for better performance
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
  },

  // Add development plugins
  plugins: dependencyHandlers().concat(plugins), // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define

  // Tell babel that we want to hot-reload
  babelQuery: {
    // require.resolve solves the issue of relative presets when dealing with
    // locally linked packages. This is an issue with babel and webpack.
    // See https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/149 and
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1866
    presets: ['babel-preset-react-hmre'].map(require.resolve),
  },

  // Emit a source map for easier debugging
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
});

/**
 * Select which plugins to use to optimize the bundle's handling of
 * third party dependencies.
 *
 * If there is a dllPlugin key on the project's package.json, the
 * Webpack DLL Plugin will be used.  Otherwise the CommonsChunkPlugin
 * will be used.
 *
 */
function dependencyHandlers() {
  // Don't do anything during the DLL Build step
  if (process.env.BUILDING_DLL) { return []; }

  // If the package.json does not have a dllPlugin property, use the CommonsChunkPlugin
  if (!dllPlugin) {
    return [
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        children: true,
        minChunks: 2,
        async: true,
      }),
    ];
  }

  const dllPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), dllPlugin.path || 'node_modules/react-boilerplate-dlls');

  /**
   * If DLLs aren't explicitly defined, we assume all production dependencies listed in package.json
   * Reminder: You need to exclude any server side dependencies by listing them in dllConfig.exclude
   */
  if (!dllPlugin.dlls) {
    const manifestPath = path.resolve(dllPath, 'reactBoilerplateDeps.json');

    if (!fs.existsSync(manifestPath)) {
      logger.error('The DLL manifest is missing. Please run `npm run build:dll`');
      process.exit(0);
    }

    return [
      new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
        context: process.cwd(),
        manifest: require(manifestPath), // eslint-disable-line global-require
      }),
    ];
  }

  // If DLLs are explicitly defined, we automatically create a DLLReferencePlugin for each of them.
  const dllManifests = Object.keys(dllPlugin.dlls).map((name) => path.join(dllPath, `/${name}.json`));

  return dllManifests.map((manifestPath) => {
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
      if (!fs.existsSync(manifestPath)) {
        logger.error(`The following Webpack DLL manifest is missing: ${path.basename(manifestPath)}`);
        logger.error(`Expected to find it in ${dllPath}`);
        logger.error('Please run: npm run build:dll');

        process.exit(0);
      }
    }

    return new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: process.cwd(),
      manifest: require(manifestPath), // eslint-disable-line global-require
    });
  });
}

/**
 * We dynamically generate the HTML content in development so that the different
 * DLL Javascript files are loaded in script tags and available to our application.
 */
function templateContent() {
  const html = fs.readFileSync(
    path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'app/index.html')
  ).toString();

  if (!dllPlugin) { return html; }

  const doc = cheerio(html);
  const body = doc.find('body');
  const dllNames = !dllPlugin.dlls ? ['reactBoilerplateDeps'] : Object.keys(dllPlugin.dlls);

  dllNames.forEach((dllName) => body.append(`<script data-dll='true' src='/${dllName}.dll.js'></script>`));

  return doc.toString();
}
```

webpack.base.babel

```
/**
 * COMMON WEBPACK CONFIGURATION
 */
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = (options) => ({
  entry: options.entry,
  output: Object.assign({ // Compile into js/build.js
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
  }, options.output), // Merge with env dependent settings
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/, // Transform all .js files required somewhere with Babel
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /styles/],
      query: options.babelQuery,
    }, {
      // Do not transform vendor's CSS with CSS-modules
      // The point is that they remain in global scope.
      // Since we require these CSS files in our JS or CSS files,
      // they will be a part of our compilation either way.
      // So, no need for ExtractTextPlugin here.
      test: /\.css$/,
      include: [/node_modules/, /styles/],
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    },
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      include: [/node_modules/, /styles/],
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    }, {
      test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
      include: [/node_modules/, /styles/],
      loader: 'file-loader',
    }, {
      test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
      loaders: [
        'file-loader',
        {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          query: {
            progressive: true,
            optimizationLevel: 7,
            interlaced: false,
            pngquant: {
              quality: '65-90',
              speed: 4,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    }, {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'html-loader',
    }, {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader',
    }, {
      test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader',
      query: {
        limit: 10000,
      },
    }],
  },
  plugins: options.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      // make fetch available
      fetch: 'exports-loader?self.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
    }),
    // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, in order to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
    // inside your code for any environment checks; UglifyJS will automatically
    // drop any unreachable code.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        OUR_AUTH_VAR: JSON.stringify(process.env.OUR_AUTH_VAR),
      },
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\.\/locale$/, null, false, /js$/),
    // new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.\/locale$/),
  ]),
  resolve: {
    modules: ['app', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.jsx',
      '.react.js',
    ],
    mainFields: [
      'browser',
      'jsnext:main',
      'main',
    ],
    alias: {
        'react': path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
      }
  },
  devtool: options.devtool,
  target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
  performance: options.performance || {},
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you are using javascript (not typescript) make sure that your `\.js$` webpack rule is not excluding `node_modules`.

Comment: I have updated the question with webpack dev file,please have a look.

Comment: are you using some starter? i can't see `module.rules` in your webpack config, how babel is working?

Comment: yeah we have the `webpack.base.babel.js ` but we don't have `module.rules` defined anywhere..

Comment: I have updated the question with base webpack. please check

Comment: @PrabhatMishra yeah i can see you are using very old version of webpack)) so there are `module.loaders`. So in `js` rule where loader is `babel` try to remove `node_modules` from `exclude: [/node_modules/, /styles/]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203458/discussion-between-prabhat-mishra-and-nickbullock).